# Is this a error of GitLab Documentation?

Tags: docker, gitlab

I use the GitLab CE docker image and want to expose GitLab on different ports from host.

I read some instructions from the [offical documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#expose-gitlab-on-different-ports):

> To expose Web interface on 8929 and SSH service on 2289 use a following docker run command:

```
sudo docker run --detach \
    --hostname gitlab.example.com \
    --publish 8929:80 --publish 2289:22 \
    ...
    gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

> The second, you need to configure gitlab.rb:

```
#Set external_url:
external_url "http://gitlab.example.com:8929/"
...
# Set gitlab_shell_ssh_port:
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2289
```

but after start the container I found that *in the container* gitlab can be accessed from http://localhost:8929 but not http://localhost:80.
Maybe the document makes a mistake, but the mistake is so stupid, I am not sure.

I think the second step is not needed, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working as it should? Maybe you need to rephrase your question to state what you actually want it to do, but this is how it works:

The Docker container exposes port 80. Now, specifying `--publish 8929:80` on the command line tells it to make the port 80 available on port 8929 on the host. That's why http://localhost:8929 correctly shows the Gitlab installation.

That also means that setting the port in the external url is indeed neccessary, otherwise Gitlab will not be able to correctly build URLs that link to the installation.

If you just want to use the exposed ports verbatim, without remapping, just use the `-P` flag for `docker run`.

For further information see the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports)

Comment: in the container http://localhost:8929 shows correctly. But I want to access this url from host.  In fact , access this url from host return a connect refused.  And it worked as I wanted without configure `gitlab.rb`.